# node application is spawning a python child process which is doing some heavy work. I want to get real time data on node from python script

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, child-process, spawn

Node application is creating a python child process for some heavy work and printing a lots of statements. I am not able to get the data in real-time from python script.Also Is interprocess communication helpful in this matter

i tried spawning the python process in unbuffered mode and flushing the data in python script. i tried fork also for this purpose but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
 const subprocess = spawn('python', ["-u",
   path.join(__dirname, 'script.py')
]);
subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`data:${data}`);
 });
 subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`error:${data}`);
 });
 subprocess.stderr.on('close', () => {
    console.log("Closed");
 });
```

```py
print("hello",flush=True)
print("hello",flush=True)
print("hello",flush=True)
print("hello",flush=True)
```

i expect the output

```
data:hello
data:hello
data:hello
data:hello
```

,but getting output as:

```
data:hello
hello
hello
data:hello
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is much that you can do, not if the Python code is producing data very quickly. The way Node dispatches events you can't be sure that events will be dispatched faster than your Python process produces data.

Comment: can we use messaging queue between node and python script without any external library or module? If yes, then how?

Comment: Perhaps, but I wouldn't know how to do that offhand. I'd have to ask you this, however: Is it so important to get the data one piece at a time that you'd be willing to slow down the Python process just to do that? Because that's what the kind of messaging queue you're talking about would do -- force the Python process to pause while waiting for the Node process to receive each individual piece of data.

Comment: If we add `time.sleep(0.01)` in the child process it works. If we reduce it further to 0.001, it runs into the same problem as you pointed out. If I had to guess, it takes time for the python to flush stdout, and in between if any output comes in it allows it to pass. I could be wrong. If you can live with sleep time, go for it. Else it would be better to redirect the output to a file or a mechanism for IPC like using unix domain sockets, mmap, zeromq, or even some db like redis or sqlite3.

Comment: thank you. @kshetline I agree its not worthless to slow down node. though i created a message queue by myself which does not wait for child process, it just put the message into the message queue.